# Aligning an Image and text within a Div CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an image and text within a `div` so it looks like the following

---

IMAGE          TEXT

---

However when I get them aligned as such, the background colour of the `div` no longer appears.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="introduction">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Good luck!!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.introduction {
    margin: 0 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.image {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.text {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the two floats in there side by side makes the parent container's height effectively 0. You can put a div with a style="clear:both;" before the parent's closing tag and you will get your background back.

```
<div class="introduction">
<div class="image">
    <img src="" />
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>
    Text
    </p>
    <p>Good luck!!</p>
</div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: Cheers, if I reduce the size of the browser, the text goes out of the div. any idea why it would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may achieve what you want:

```
<style>
    .introduction{
        margin:0px;
        padding:5px;
        background-color:orange;
    }

    .introduction img{
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
    }

    .introduction p{
        padding-left:50px;
        background-color:blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="introduction">
    <img src="img/can_25.png" />
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Good Luck</p>
</div>
```

Since your p's aren't floated, they will hold your div open .. depending on the size of your image.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you 2 solutions:

**1)** If you want to your output look like this:

```
IMAGE TEXT 
IMAGE TEXT
      TEXT
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="whole">
    <img class="ib" src="myimg.png" alt="my img" />
    <p class="ib">my text my text my text my text my text my text my text is so short I will die alone</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ib{ display:inline-block;}
.whole{ vertical-align:top}

.ib img{width:30%; border:0;}
.ib p{width:70%;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

**2)** or like this:

```
IMAGE TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="myimg.png" alt="my img" class="leftimg" />
<p>my text my text my text is so short I will die alone</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.leftimg {
   float:left; 
   margin-right:5px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/b66J8/37/